# How to count child .class of parent #id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hello Stack Overflowians,

I seem to be incorrectly using .length in combination with the child selector (>).  The full script is below, but here's the problematic line:

```
$(id > '.fade-cycle-element').length;
```

If I simply select by .class `$('.fade-cycle-element').length`, jQuery returns the count of *all* matching elements on the page, rather than the number of matching children of a specific parent #id.  If I use the selector method above, jQuery returns 0.

What am I doing wrong?  Many thanks in advance for your help.

Kindest Regards,

./ndm

```
/* This script takes a set of elements (e.g., images) and rotates them according to a 

specified rate.
 * 
 * Example HTML:
 * <div class="fade-cycle-element-wrapper" data-rate="4000">
 *   <img class="fade-cycle-element" src="01.jpg" />
 *   <img class="fade-cycle-element" src="02.jpg" />
 *   <img class="fade-cycle-element" src="03.jpg" />
 * </div>
 *
 * The idea for this script is based on Brian McNitt's rotating image script:
 * 
 *   http://trendmedia.com/news/infinite-rotating-images-using-jquery-javascript
 *   
 *   Copyright (c) 2010 TrendMedia Technologies, Inc., Brian McNitt. 
 *   All rights reserved.
 *    
 *   Released under the GPL license
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php
 *   
 *   **********************************************************************
 *   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
 *   WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. 
 *   **********************************************************************
 * 
 */

function elementRotate(elemID) {

  //get cycle rate and set derivatives
  var id = '#' + elemID;
  var cycle = $(id).data('rate');
  var start = (cycle*.25);
  var fade = (cycle*.25);

  //queue up the elements and start the cycle
  var elements = $(id > '.fade-cycle-element').length;
  var current = 0;
  $(id > '.fade-cycle-element').eq(current).fadeIn(start);

  //cycle through elements    
  var engine = setInterval(function(){
    $(id > '.fade-cycle-element').eq(current).fadeOut(fade);
    if (current == (elements - 1)) {
      current = 0;
    } else {
      current++;
    }
    $(id > '.fade-cycle-element').eq(current).fadeIn(fade);
  }, cycle);

};

$(window).load(function() {

  var elemSetCount = 1;
  $('.fade-cycle-element-wrapper').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "elemSet" + elemSetCount++);
    var elemSetID = $(this).attr('id');
    elementRotate(elemSetID)
  });

});
```

Comment: You're confusing the `>` CSS selector with the `>` JavaScript operator. If it's a CSS selector, it has to appear within a string. If it appears as a stand-alone literal, it's parsed as the greater-than operator.

Comment: `$('#id > .fade-cycle-element').length;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're performing a comparison here, not writing a selector! You're comparing `id` and the string `'.fade-cycle-element'` and passing the boolean result into the jQuery function.

You should be doing instead:

```
$(id + ' > .fade-cycle-element').length;
```

Comment: @karthikr So he does -- the OP just edited with his full code. Edited my answer to correct.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I forgot to include the full script!